# What is the best temperature to germinate Haworthiopsis limifolia seeds?

Tags: seeds, succulents, germination, propagation

I have a batch of [Haworthiopsis limifolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haworthiopsis_limifolia) seeds that I collected from my own plants and would like to sow.

I won't ask when to sow them, because your climate may differ. I will rather ask what temperature range is best, and what difference between day and night temperatures triggers germination.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find relevant information on this, but I think I figured out a way to answer this question.

We know that [Haworthiopsis limifolia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haworthiopsis_limifolia), formerly known as Haworthia limifolia is native to a few countries in southern Africa, thus we can check native climate since its germination process occurs outdoors.

To narrow our search we choose a country that's small and has a uniform climate on its territory, [Swaziland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swaziland) for example. Usually Wikipedia shows monthly averages (highs and lows) for capital cities, so we check the climate in [Mbabane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbabane#Geography_and_climate). Haworthia starts its germination process in spring, and spring in southern hemisphere occurs roughly at opposite time than in northern hemisphere. That's why we can look at spring temperatures in Mbabane to determine the range needed for seeds to germinate.

Furthermore, we can easily see that at this specific location average rainfall starts to rise in October, so we can assume that's when cactus and succulent seeds start to germinate.

In conclusion, I say there's a great chance that your seeds will need a daily temperature above 22°C (72°F) and at least 11°C (52°F) during night time.

I also want to add that I've seen on some sites that a temperature of [17°C (63°F)](http://b-and-t-world-seeds.com/cartall.asp?species=Haworthia%20limifolia%20densely%20white%20striated&sref=432815) or a range from [15 to 20°C (59-68°F)](http://www.haworthia.info/) is required but I think this is just an average between day and night. Indeed, (22 + 11) / 2 = 16.5°C, so I guess my assumption is right.